# How to sum cells once per day?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to add the value of one particular cell to that of another particular cell once per day?

e.g. Cell A2 contains a value (which may change). Whatever that value is at midnight, add it to the value of cell B2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### if your question is how to add +1 to your A2 value every day:

not really, but you can trick it... today's date value is:

[image]

so if your A2 it's let's say 20 you can use this in B2:

```
=A2+VALUE(TODAY())-44580
```

[image]

eg at midnight B2 will become 21 and next day it will be 22, etc.

### if your question is how to add A2 to B2 on a daily basis:

it is possible only with script